# SELinux Denial while making video call and transcription at the same time

Tags: flutter, dart, selinux, agora.io

I am using [sound_stream](https://pub.dev/packages/sound_stream) package to get stream from microphone and sending it to Google Speech To Text Api. It is working fine when I try to use it simple screen like just one button to start listening and getting transcription. I can get text instantaneously, but if I try it during the video call(agora_rtc_engine), no text appears and as an output I am getting this message:

```
W/Thread-105(27996): type=1400 audit(0.0:14846): avc: denied { read } for name="stat" dev="proc" 
ino=4026532094 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 
tcontext=u:object_r:proc_stat:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

I don't understand what is the problem here? I think it might be about Agora Rtc and Sound Stream Package try to use microphone at the same. If so how can I fix this issue? If it's not, what s the problem here?

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use speech_to_text api while you're on call or during an active stream. To solve this you need to use an API that can convert speech to text during a live stream. You can try using the following solutions:

- Google: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize
- IBM: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/text-to-speech-java

Comment: Thank you for your attendance, with this API, can I capture video stream  automatically? I will implement it with Java native and API document is not good enough. All I want to do video translation in real time

Comment: You can go through this : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/cloud-client/src/main/java/com/example/speech/Recognize.java

It has sample codes on how to add transcription in Java.

Comment: thank you but I can already get transcription, my question is that how can I get transcription during the video call, because I can't use same microphone to feed google speech api and video sdk at the same time